# Embedded Tomcat 8 Fails to to start

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a jar that deploys and runs in a standalone tomcat 8.0.28 server with Java 8.0.66

I wish to run it from an embedded Tomcat to run integration tests.
The war deploys but fails to start, I ran out of ideas, I am getting the following error:

```
Dec 07, 2015 6:11:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9191"]
Dec 07, 2015 6:11:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool 
getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 07, 2015 6:11:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService 
startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Dec 07, 2015 6:11:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Dec 07, 2015 5:43:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig 
getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
Dec 07, 2015 5:43:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].
StandardContext[/StrateboBackEnd]]
...
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
Failed to start component StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].
StandardContext[/myApp]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
```

I have the following setup for the embed tomcat

```
final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(9191);
File baseDir = new File(".");
Context context = tomcat.addContext("", baseDir.getAbsolutePath());
tomcat.addWebapp("/Myapp", "C://Users//Add//git//Myapp//build//libs//Myapp-1.1.war");
tomcat.enableNaming();
ContextResource res = new ContextResource();
res.setName("jdbc/myDatabase");
res.setType("javax.sql.DataSource");
res.setAuth("Container");
res.setProperty("username", "username");
res.setProperty("password", "password");
res.setProperty("driverClassName","net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
res.setProperty("url", "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433//myDatabase");
res.setProperty("maxTotal", "10");
res.setProperty("maxIdle", "10");
res.setProperty("maxWaitMillis", "10000");
res.setProperty("removeAbandonedTimeout","300"); 
res.setProperty("defaultAutoCommit","true"); 
context.getNamingResources().addResource(res);
tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

I have a context.xml that I use for normal deployment but this does not get read in embedded from what I can tell.

Since the jar works on a standalone I know that the jar is not the problem

There is this Info line
INFO: No global web.xml found
Which might point to an issue but could not find a reference
Just in case here is the relevant part of my gradle file for dependencies

```
compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:8.0.28'
compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.28'
compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.28'
compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.0.28'
compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.28'
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated?
For an extra point is there any way to get tomcat to give better feedback as to what it is not liking?

Answer (score 1):

After some research it looks like most of the questions on StackOverflow regarding embedded Tomcat 8 remain unanswered there does not seem to be interest or development in this area.  As this was for integration testing I setup a tomcat server on my Jenkins machine and Jenkins pushes the war unto it, restarts it then runs the integration tests. This work even though it may not be the most elegant.